# No changes are pushed when using hg-git

Tags: mercurial, github, hg-git

I'm trying to get the hg-git extension working under Windows and after hours of fiddling, I finally seem to have it working. However, nothing shows up in my git repository even though the output of hg push reads:

```
importing Hg objects into Git
creating and sending data
    github::refs/heads/master => GIT:8d946209
[command completed successfully Wed Oct 20 15:26:47 2010]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And it seems that just after I asked this, I made a trivial change. This was picked up and pushed. So it seems that you have to wait until you've made a new commit in order for hg-git to pick it up.

Comment: Can you explain what you did? Especially did hg-git missed some changesets in the first run?

Answer (score 50):

Try issuing the command `hg bookmark -f master`

(use `-f` to force an existing bookmark to move)

Then try pushing again.

This works because [Hg-Git pushes your bookmarks up to the Git server as branches](http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git) and will pull Git branches down and set them up as bookmarks. (from the official README.md)

Comment: I have limited experience with git, but I found https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hg-git/x8QYBH-fPs4
which might be related. Does anyone with git experience have anything to say about this?

Comment: I wish I could favorite an answer. Hopefully when I return here, I'll read these comments and realize this is the correct answer for the general case. :)

Comment: In my case the master bookmark became 'inactive' after I put a tag on a commit. This meant the master bookmark would no longer be updated automatically (until I ran the above command to make it 'active' again).

Answer (score 0):

I had chosen to 'Initialize this repository with a README'. This meant I ended up with two heads, which I couldn't `hg merge` because one had a bookmark.

To get pushing working, I had to:

- configure hg-git and github remote as per https://blog.glyphobet.net/essay/2029
- pull from github and update
- force the merge (checking which id to use with `hg heads`),
- commit the merge
- add a trivial change to a file (add a space char to the end),
- commit, then
- move the bookmark to the tip
- push to my configured github remote

This ended up with commands as follows (substituting in `<x>` sections)

```
hg pull github
hg update
hg merge <revision-id-of-incoming-git-version>
hg addremove
hg commit -m 'merged with github'
 # make some trivial change to a file - eg add a space where it doesn't cause harm
hg add <changed-file>
hg commit -m 'trivial change'
hg bookmark -f master
hg push github
```

make sure you pick the remote revision for the merge above - if you don't it doesn't work!