# Hg-git stopped working for multiple branches

Tags: git, github, mercurial, bitbucket, hg-git

I keep the [main repo](https://bitbucket.org/scriptoid/diagramo) on mercurial but [made a clone](https://github.com/alexgheorghiu/diagramo/) with hg-git for git lovers.

The problem is that in the mercurial repo I went back to a previous commit, created a new anonymous branch and closed the old one. (Reason: postpone development of a feature)

After that I saw that hg-git stopped working.

I tried even to force the commit but still not succeeded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No changes are pushed when using hg-git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982006/no-changes-are-pushed-when-using-hg-git)

Comment: The statement "hg-git stopped working" is not very clear... can you describe that in more detail so that people reading this can determine if it applies to their situation more easily?

Answer (score 11):

Ok...finally founded the answer on another hg-git [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982006/no-changes-are-pushed-when-using-hg-git?rq=1)

So it seems that you have to update the "master" bookmark to current branch.

```
hg bookmark -f master
```