# Hg-git not pushing commits on Github

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, hg-git

I have this problem with `hg-git` where I can't push any commits to `Github` anymore.
When before I had no problems at all.

I have a Mercurial repo in `Bitbucket` where I push to Github, with

```
hg push git+ssh://git@github.com:userid/MyRepo.git
```

This used to work, however now, when I do this, `hg` always return that there was no changes and the commits are not updated to `Github`. It is able to connect, no problems of that kind. It is really weird, something might have gone corrupted. So I did a fresh

```
hg clone
```

of the repo from `Bitbucket`, checked if the commit history is there and then do the hg push to Github again, still it does not find any changes.

What could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hg-git stopped working for multiple branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175561/hg-git-stopped-working-for-multiple-branches)

Answer (score 1):

According to 'Use' section in https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/overview, you should switch from colon to slash after the host:

```
hg push git+ssh://git@github.com/userid/MyRepo.git
```