# Why is my git repository empty after using hggit to push my mercurial repository to it?

Tags: git, mercurial, hg-git

We have a very large Mercurial repository - about 11GB with approximately 130,000 commits.  I am trying to convert it to git using the hggit extension of Mercurial, and I am having a strange experience.

As a side note, I am doing this on Windows 10

First, I create an empty directory, and call `git init` to initialize the git repository.

Then, I go to the hg directory and issue the (unusual to me) command `hg bookmark hg` as per a few articles I read.

Then, I issue `hg push c:\path\to\repo`

Here is the result:

[image]

It appears that the repository was successfully processed and pushed.

However, when I go to the git repository directory, it is empty, except for the .git directory. In that git directory, all the tags are present, and there is a large *.pack file of about 11GB, which I assume is related to our repository, given the size.

I thought that I needed to `checkout` a branch before the files would show up, but an attempt to checkout a recent branch results in:

```
error: pathspec 'rio' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

So my question is:  **What do I need to do to get my files to appear in the git respository?**

Comment: What does `git status` show ? Do you have a `.git/refs` directory ? What do `git branch` and `git tag` show ?

Comment: @LeGEC -- `git branch` shows a single branch called `hg`  `git tag` showed a huge list of our tags.

Comment: There is a .git/refs directory.

Comment: What bookmarks do you have in your hg repository? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3982006/1256452. See also the `git.branch_bookmark_suffix configuration` setting: https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/src/default/

Comment: I only had one bookmark called 'hg'.

Comment: If `hg push` is like `git push`, only selected refs are updated, it's for communications among a team, not a fast-export replacement.  [See the git docs for migrating](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git), they talk about avoiding what looks like your symptoms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert mercurial repository to git repository without losing branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129896/how-to-convert-mercurial-repository-to-git-repository-without-losing-branches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `git tag --list` and `git branch --list` to view the actual names of the references created by your `hg push` command.

You can then checkout the appropriate branch or tag.

---

If you want to create a branch with a more explicit name, run the regular command :

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name [hash or tag or branch]
```

For example : if you want to create a `master` branch starting from the same point as the branch named `hg` :

```
git checkout -b master hg
```

---

(following the link posted in comment by @torek) : [hg-git's Readme, "Usage" section](https://dev.heptapod.net/mercurial/hg-git#usage)

> Hg-Git pushes your bookmarks up to the Git server as branches and will
>   pull Git branches down and set them up as bookmarks.

If you want to create more branches from specific points in your mercurial repo, you will have to bookmark them.

---

*Extra details about branches :*

I'm not used to Mercurial, but from what I gathered, branches in Mercurial are objects, which have distinct attributes (such as : when was it created ? by who ? etc ...),
as opposed to git, where branches are just shallow references to commits, which can be automatically updated (e.g : with `git commit`, `git merge`, etc ...).

For example : in git, with the following diagram :

```
a--*--*--x--*--*--*--*--*--* <- develop
          \
           *--*--* <- feature1
```

You can find info about each individual commit (each `*` in the diagram) :
who created it, when was it committed, etc ...
but you cannot say for sure if `develop` started at `a` and `feature1` started at `x`, or if it was the other way around.

The doc for hg-git states, in its "[branch_bookmark_suffix](https://dev.heptapod.net/mercurial/hg-git#gitbranch_bookmark_suffix)" paragraph, that this is the reason why `hg-git` maps `git` branches to `hg` bookmarks, and that you should double your branches with bookmarks. See the example I posted as another answer to this question.

Comment: `git branch --all` lists a single branch, `hg`.  I can checkout this branch, but that appears to be it.

Comment: I should add that there is no `master` branch.

Comment: look at the history of the `hg` branch : does it match the list of commits you expect ?

Comment: about the `master` branch : you are right, it is not created in an empty repo.

Comment: I looked at the `hg` branch in TortoiseGit, and all the history is there on the hg branch, yes.

Comment: thanks for your help.  All the information appears to be there correctly if I open the repository in SourceTree.

Comment: @NickHodges : to give a more concrete answer, would you care to give an example of a branch you have on Mercurial, which you would like to see on git ?

Comment: Sure -- we have literally thousands of branches.  One I'd like to go to is `7.3.20`

Comment: @NickHodges: ok, and, with such a name, it is a *branch* (not a tag), right ?

Comment: Correct, it is a branch.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to : how to push branch `7.3.20` from mercurial to git ?

*preamble* : the [branch_bookmark_suffix](https://dev.heptapod.net/mercurial/hg-git#gitbranch_bookmark_suffix) suffix paragraph of hg git's README indicates the steps to follow

1. choose a suffix for your mercurial bookmarks (I will use `_git`) :

   ```
   # edit hg config, in the [git] section, add :
   [git]
   branch_bookmark_suffix = _git
   ```
2. in your mercurial repo, create a bookmark which duplicates the branch :

   ```
   hg bookmark 7.3.20_git 7.3.20
   ```
3. use hggit to push to the `git` repo :

   ```
   hg push
   ```
4. in your git repo, check if a `7.3.20` branch has been created :

   ```
   git branch --list
   ```

You would need to repeat step `2.` for all the branches which you want to push to git.

Comment: So if I have 1000 branches, I have to do this 1000 times?  Argh!

Comment: You would probably want to replace step 2 with a script that creates all the bookmarks you want.